# bootstrap dl list not show on side of fontawesome icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have icon and `dl` list for show Together like this :

```
.phone {
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #333 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    color: #262626;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 30px 23px;
}
.dl-horizontal dt {
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.dl-horizontal {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.col-md-4 i {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px !important;
}
.col-md-12 i {
    margin: 0px 12px 0px 15px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="ef-widget-inner">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 nopadding"> <i class="fa fa-phone phone"></i>

        <dl class="dl-horizontal"> <dt>Title 1.................</dt>

            <dd><a href="contact.php"><span><i>28311</i></span></a>
            </dd> <dt>Title 2</dt>

            <dd><a href="contact.php"><span><i>28312</i></span></a>
            </dd> <dt>Title 3</dt>

            <dd><a href="contact.php"><span><i>28314</i></span></a>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

BUT, `dl` list show in bottom of icon. how do can i show `dl` list On side of icon?!

demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rq9gsqfq/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `.dl-horizontal` the css property `display: inline-block`, otherwise it will be displayed as `block` which takes up 100% of the width.

```css
.phone {
  font-size: 10px;
  background: #333 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: #262626;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 30px 23px;
}
.dl-horizontal dt {
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.dl-horizontal {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.col-md-4 i {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px !important;
}
.col-md-12 i {
  margin: 0px 12px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ef-widget-inner">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 nopadding"> <i class="fa fa-phone phone"></i>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal"> <dt>Title 1.................</dt>
      <dd><a href="contact.php"><span><i>28311</i></span></a>
      </dd> <dt>Title 2</dt>

      <dd><a href="contact.php"><span><i>28312</i></span></a>
      </dd> <dt>Title 3</dt>

      <dd><a href="contact.php"><span><i>28314</i></span></a>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```